# Keeping the "0" digit in front of a number

Tags: java, numbers, zero

I'm making a small number reversal game. The user gets the 10 unique digits (0-9) in a random order, and has to put them in order by reversing them. However, when the 0 is in front such as:

0123456789 becomes 123456789

0000192837465 becomes 192837465

0(anything after) becomes (anything after)

The 0 disappears automatically. Any way to stop this? Since this number is constantly changing, I wish the 0 to simply stay in the number.

PS: In Java

Comment: You can't use numbers, because leading zeroes are non really part of what is stored.  Instead, you'll have to use a string or something similar.  If you can show actual code, maybe more can be said here.

Answer (score 6):

Don’t represent the digits as a numeric type, use a string. After all your program is manipulating a string of characters, the individual characters happen to be digits but it’s not important that you evaluate it as a number.

When you write a program you need to consider your requirements and think of what data structure best handles them, when you use the first thing that comes to mind you can get yourself into trouble.

Comment: I see. I need to do more work on my planning, thanks for the help.

Comment: Here's my completed code if you're interested in seeing how I did it. https://pastebin.com/b03Fjuvv